# WebStorm Evaluate XPath Expression and view results

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, webstorm, xpath

When I use the *Evaluate XPath Expression* dialog to execute XPath against an XML document (a document external to the project), it works and highlights the matches in the document, but it doesn't display a list of matching results in the bottom panel like I would expect. It displays this message above a greyed out *Find* tab:

[image]

Clinking on the link doesn't do anything, and I can't find options for *Find* in Preferences or in any of the menus. I also looked for settings related to *'Project and Libraries'*  but didn't find anything. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Show results in Usage View" option doesn't currently work for files that doesn't belong to current project; please follow [IDEA-164949](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164949) for updates